# Maximum number of partitions in a table MYSQL 5.6.10

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am looking to do a range partition on one of my tables, this would be range partition. I was wondering what are the maximum number of partitions we can have in a table. I am running MYSQL 5.6.10.

Ideally I am looking to create around 8000 partitions. Also can someone advise that if so many partitions will effect performance or some way hurt database. I am also using `innodb_file_per_table=ON`

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by creating 8000 partitions?

Comment: You might want to check this out before you create 8k partitions: https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/12/05/how-many-partitions-can-you-have/

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html#partitioning-limitations-max-partitions):

> Prior to MySQL 5.6.7, the maximum possible number of partitions for a given table not using the NDB storage engine was 1024. Beginning with MySQL 5.6.7, this limit is increased to 8192 partitions. Regardless of the MySQL Server version, this maximum includes subpartitions.